# X-Real-IP header confusion in nginx

Tags: nginx, header, ip-address, identification

My nginx config is -

```
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    set_real_ip_from 55.55.55.1;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    real_ip_recursive on;
```

I would like to know if I understand this config correctly.
Let us say a user has a machine - 
1. At ip `11.11.11.11` 
2. The user is behind a proxy which has an IP `22.22.22.22` 
3. User sends a request, which reaches the load balancer at `55.55.55.1`, which routes it to nginx.

Then, once nginx has done its work, the request will have following headers reaching the server - 
a. `X-Forwarded-For: [11.11.11.11, 22.22.22.22, 55.55.55.1]` 
b. `X-Real-IP: 22.22.22.22` (since nginx will recurse on `X-Forwarded-For` from end to array to start of array, and find the first untrusted ip) 
c. If `X-Forwarded-For` does not exist in a request, then `$remote_addr` value is used in `X-Real-IP` header, otherwise it is over-written by recursing on `X-Forwarded-For` header array, taking into consideration `set_real_ip_from` rule(s).

Please let me know if points 'a', 'b' and 'c' are correct or incorrect. If incorrect, I would like to know the reason why?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is a loopback address - so it cannot be the internet-facing address of your load balancer. And assuming that every proxy in the chain appends to the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Comment: @RichardSmith Edited!

Comment: Your understanding matches my understanding. Are you experiencing a specific problem?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was not sure if I understood it correctly!