# Accessing docker real client IP in docker container when haproxy itself is running as docker container

Tags: django, docker, http, docker-compose, haproxy

My app runs on cluster of 6 docker containers. Three of them are haproxy, nodejs (runs react app) and wsgi (runs django app).

Following is my docker compose file (relevant sections are `haproxy`, `wsgi` and `nodejs`):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:11
        volumes:
            - myapp_postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - type: tmpfs
              target: /dev/shm
              tmpfs:
                size: 536870912 # 512MB
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: mymodule
            POSTGRES_USER: myapp
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myapp123
        networks:
            - myapp_network

    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4:5.4
        volumes:
            - myapp_pgadmin_volume:/var/lib/pgadmin
        environment:
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: myapp@cse.myinsti.ac.in
            PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: myapp123
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        networks:
            - myapp_network
            
    redis:
        image: redis:6.2.4
        volumes:
            - myapp_redis_volume:/data
        networks:
            - myapp_network

    wsgi:
        image: wsgi:myapp3
        volumes:
            - /myapp/frontend/static/
            - ./wsgi/myapp:/myapp
            - /myapp/frontend/clientApp/node_modules
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis
        ports:
            - 9090
            - 3000:3000
            - 8000:8000
        environment:
            C_FORCE_ROOT: 'true'
            SERVICE_PORTS: 9090
        networks:
            - myapp_network
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            update_config:
                parallelism: 1
                delay: 10s
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 120s

    nodejs:
        image: nodejs:myapp3
        volumes:
            - ./nodejs/frontend:/frontend
            - /frontend/node_modules
        depends_on:
            - wsgi
        ports:
            - 9000:9000 # development
            - 9999:9999 # production
        environment:
            BACKEND_API_URL: http://0.0.0.0:3000
        networks:
            - myapp_network

    nginx:
        image: nginx-brotli:1.21.0
        volumes:
            - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
            - ./wsgi/myapp:/myapp:ro
            - myapp_nginx_volume:/var/log/nginx/
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        networks:
            - myapp_network
            
    haproxy:
        image: haproxy:2.3.9
        volumes:
            - ./haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/:ro
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        depends_on:
            - wsgi
            - nodejs
            - nginx
        ports:
            - 9763:80
        networks:
            - myapp_network
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]

volumes:
    myapp_postgres_volume:
    myapp_redis_volume:
    myapp_nginx_volume:
    myapp_pgadmin_volume:

networks:
    myapp_network:
        driver: overlay
```

Below is my `haproxy.cfg` (relevant sections are `frontend` and `backend api`):

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    maxconn 4096

defaults
    mode http
    log global
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend www
    bind *:80
    mode http
    option httplog
    log global
    default_backend http
    option forwardfor
    
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request set-header X-Client-IP %[src]
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto http

    acl is_static path_beg /static /media /favicon.ico /robots.txt /humans.txt
    # acl is_static path_end .png .jpg .css .js .jsx
    acl is_stats path_beg /stats
    acl is_api path_beg /api
    acl is_admin path_beg /admin
    acl is_swagger path_beg /swagger
    acl is_redoc path_beg /redoc
    
    use_backend static if is_static
    use_backend stats if is_stats
    use_backend api if is_api
    use_backend django_admin if is_admin
    use_backend django_admin if is_swagger
    use_backend django_admin if is_redoc
    
    default_backend http
    
backend http
    balance roundrobin
    server nodejs nodejs:9999 check

backend api
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request add-header X-Client-IP %[src]
    http-request add-header X-FrontEnd-IP %[dst]
    server wsgi wsgi:3000 check
    http-request set-path %[path,regsub(^/api/,/)] 

backend django_admin
    balance roundrobin
    server wsgi wsgi:9090 check

backend static
    server nginx nginx:80

backend stats
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats realm HAProxy\ Statistics
    stats uri /stats
    stats auth root:toor
```

Note that docker compose has `9763:80` which maps port `9763` to port `80`. Note that haproxy.cfg has `bind *:80` which makes it listed to port `80`. So all requests to port `9763` are forwarded to haproxy. My react app makes REST API calls to `http://0.0.0.0:9763/api/`. So this hits docker, then is forwarded to port `80` and gets handled by haproxy. Next haproxy forwards this to `backend api` as can be seen in `haproxy.cfg`:

```
use_backend api if is_api
```

In the django app (i.e. `backend api`), I want to log IP of the browser from where react app accessed. So, as you can see above, I have added following lines to `backend api` section of `haproxy.cfg` (after referring to various online articles [1](https://serverfault.com/a/672329/546170), [2](https://serverfault.com/a/805153/546170), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72557636/difference-between-x-forwarded-for-and-x-real-ip-headers)):

```
option forwardfor
http-request add-header X-Client-IP %[src]
http-request add-header X-FrontEnd-IP %[dst]
```

However when I check `request.META` object in my django app, I see following values for different headers:

```
'HTTP_X_CLIENT_IP': '10.0.0.2,10.0.0.2'
'HTTP_X_FRONTEND_IP': '10.0.0.208'
'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '10.0.0.2'
```

However none of this is my laptop IP and seems to be some internal docker network IP. Is it because request REST to `http://0.0.0.0:9763/api/` gets mapped to port `80` by docker?
In other words, is it because my haproxy itself is running as docker container?

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify the mode in the haproxy service description in docker compose file using long syntax:

```
services:
    haproxy:
        ports:
            # - 9763:80 # short port syntax
            # long port syntax https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#long-syntax-1
            - target: 80
              published: 9763
              protocol: tcp
              mode: host
```